# HTML5: Boostrap and Datalist Polyfill Library conflict

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, google-chrome

I am using a polyfill datalist [JS library](https://github.com/Fyrd/purejs-datalist-polyfill) to give the iPad the ability to use the autosearch function when the user types in characters in an input field. Here is the original HTML:

```
<div class="col-xs-12">                    
<input type="text" id="inp_provider" placeholder="Provider" required list="provider_data"/>
<!--[if lte IE 9]><select data-datalist="provider_data"><![endif]-->
<datalist id="provider_data">
          <option value="Bruce Banner"/>
          <option value = "Reed Richers"/>
</datalist>
<!--[if lte IE 9]></select><![endif]-->
```

When I run the HTML page, the list shows at the top of the page. Below is a screenshot from my iPad.

[image: Example 1]

When I delete `<div class="col-xs-12">` and `</div>`, the list comes out correctly (at the bottom of the input field where it is supposed to be).

[image: Example 2]

The JavaScript that runs can be found [here](https://github.com/Fyrd/purejs-datalist-polyfill/blob/master/datalist.polyfill.js). Here is the CSS for the poly fill data list.

```
.datalist-polyfill {
    list-style: none;
    display: none;
    background: white;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px #999;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    max-height: 300px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

.datalist-polyfill:empty {
    display: none !important;
}

    .datalist-polyfill > li {
        padding: 3px;
        font: 13px "Lucida Grande", Sans-Serif;
    }

    .datalist-polyfill__active {
        background: #3875d7;
        color: white;
    }
```

How do I solve this issue? I am not sure where to start to solve this issue?
Device Info: iPad 2 
iOS version: 9.2 (13C75)
Chrome 57.0.2987.100

Comment: Did you try to set `position: relative` to parent class `row`?

Comment: how would one do that?